# Expo does not work with firebase emulator

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo, firebase-tools

I'm trying to access the firestore emulator (hosted locally) through my Expo app on both physical and emulated devices, which both don't work. When I make a call to the emulated firestore database, such as setting a document, it doesn't show up on the UI. However, if I run the exact same code for the real firestore it works normally.

My firebase.json config is:

```js
{
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "emulators": {
    "firestore": {
      "port": 8080
    },
  }
}
```

For the Expo app on the android emulator I set up my config as:

```js
firebase.firestore().settings({
  host: "10.0.2.2:8080", 
  ssl: false,
})
```

And for the Expo app on my physical android device:

```js
firebase.firestore().settings({
  host: "localhost:8080",  
//I've also tried "192.168.68.109:8080" my computer's IP
  ssl: false,
})
```

Comment: I think you're going to have to provide more debugging information than "it is unable to access it".

Comment: is there a way to edit these firestore host and ssl settings for realtime database? I have firestore working with expo but not realtime database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out you need to specify the host on your firebase.json as

```js
"emulators": {
    "firestore": {
      "port": 8080
      "host": "0.0.0.0"
    },
```

As for the config for the Expo app on the physical device, instead of "localhost:8080" put your computer's (or whatever your hosting on in your network) IP address followed by ":8080".

If all this still doesn't work try the command "firebase use <YOUR_PROJECT_ID>" in your project directory and it should work.

Comment: Do you know what to do for realtime database? I got firestore working but my realtime database does not connect :/

Answer (score 2):

If you're testing on a physical device, you'll have a better time connecting using your computer's IP address. Rather than hardcoding it, you can use a built-in variable: `Constants.manifest.debuggerHost?.split(":").shift()`.

Wrote up a short explanation on that here:

https://dev.to/haydenbleasel/using-the-firebase-local-emulator-with-expo-s-managed-workflow-5g5k