# Firestore emulator doesn't work with expo go

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, expo

I'm trying to use the firestore emulators with an app that I'm testing with the Expo Go app. I've set it up exactly the same as a regular react app (which works as expected). However, using the Expo Go app to test the application keeps throwing this error:

```
@firebase/firestore: Firestore (9.17.2): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. 
Connection failed 1 times. Most recent error: FirebaseError: [code=unavailable]: The operation could not be completed     
This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. 
The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.
```

I've looked at several git issues and other stackoverflow questions, but the accepted answers didn't seem to work. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65512580/expo-does-not-work-with-firebase-emulator) one gave some inspiration as to what could go wrong. And [this](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/5977) github issue where one person fixed it by updating his logrocket package. However more people seemed to be having this issue in 9.6.*.

One of my colleagues notified me that it worked fine on the Expo Go app on IOS, I'm using Android. Also connecting to the live database does work.

firebase.ts

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore, connectFirestoreEmulator } from "firebase/firestore";
import {initializeFirestore} from 'firebase/firestore';

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "...",
    authDomain: "...",
    projectId: "...",
    storageBucket: "...",
    messagingSenderId: "...",
    appId: "...",
    measurementId: "...",
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// Also tried with 
// const db = initializeFirestore(app, {
//  experimentalForceLongPolling: true,
// });
export const db = getFirestore();
// Also tried with my IP.
connectFirestoreEmulator(db, "localhost", 8080);
```

firebase.json

```json
{
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "emulators": {
    "firestore": {
      "port": 8080,
      "host": "0.0.0.0"
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true
    },
    "singleProjectMode": true
  }
}
```

TestComponent.tsx

```
import { Text, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import { addDoc, collection, getDoc, doc } from "firebase/firestore";
import { db } from "../../../firebaseConfig";

export const FirestoreTestComponent = () => {
    const handleFetchData = async () => {
        const newDoc = await addDoc(collection(db, "test"), {
            title: "This is test",
        });
        console.log("Newdoc:", newDoc);
    };

    return (
        <>
            <TouchableOpacity
                style={{
                    backgroundColor: "lightblue",
                    padding: 5,
                    borderRadius: 10,
                    marginTop: 20,
                }}
                onPress={handleFetchData}
            >
                <Text>Add data to firestore</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </>
    );
};
```

Versions:

```
"expo": "~47.0.12",
"firebase": "^9.17.2"
```

I am really grasping for any leads now since it does work on my colleagues's IOS phone but not on my android. Any idea what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

This error looks like a common IPv6 problem the Firestore Emulator has been seeing.

If you're running on an IPv6 machine `localhost` will resolve to the local IPv6 address while the Firestore Emulator is listening on the v4 address. The fix for right now is to use an explicit IPv4 address loopback: "127.0.0.1"

However if this is a physical Android device, if you're running the emulator on a laptop or desktop and using a physical Android device to run your app, the IP address is not `localhost` but the address of the attached computer. In that case you should be able to follow these instructions to connect to `localhost` of the computer:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_firestore#java

`10.0.2.2` is the IP address to try according to the above.

See also:
[Accessing localhost of PC from USB connected Android mobile device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9887621/accessing-localhost-of-pc-from-usb-connected-android-mobile-device)